# How to store data in database from views.py Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This is my models:

```
class ledger1(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    Closing_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)

class journal(models.Model):
    Date       = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    By         = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    To         = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    Debit      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True)
    Credit     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True)
```

And in my views I have done this:

```
qscb  = journal.objects.filter(By=ledger1_details.pk, Date__gte=selectdatefield_details.Start_Date, Date__lte=selectdatefield_details.End_Date)
qscb2 = journal.objects.filter(To=ledger1_details.pk, Date__gte=selectdatefield_details.Start_Date, Date__lte=selectdatefield_details.End_Date) 

total_debitcb = qscb.aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Debit'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
total_creditcb = qscb2.aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Credit'), Value(0)))['the_sum']

if(ledger1_details.group1_Name.balance_nature == 'Debit'):
    closing_balance = opening_balance + total_debitcb - total_creditcb
else:
    closing_balance = opening_balance + total_creditcb - total_debitcb
```

I want to store the value of 'closing_balance' into my model field named 'Closing_Balance'....And automatically update it when any changes are made...

Any idea anyone how it is possible in django?

Thank you

Comment: you want save `closing_balance` into `ledger1_details` ?

Comment: Yes...The value of closing_balance which I get from views into "Closing_balance" field of ledger1 model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
if(ledger1_details.group1_Name.balance_nature == 'Debit'):
    closing_balance = opening_balance + total_debitcb - total_creditcb
else:
    closing_balance = opening_balance + total_creditcb - total_debitcb 
ledger1_detail = ledger1.objects.get(pk=ledger1_details.pk)
ledger1_detail.Closing_balance = closing_balance
ledger1_detail.save(update_fields=['Closing_balance'])
```

Comment: can you check value of `closing_balance` in `if else` not `None`? And can you try again, i edit my answer for find instace again.

Comment: what version of your Django ?

Comment: Django= 2, 0, 6,

Comment: you use any `with transaction.atomic()` in start line of this code? and can you share value of `closing_balance` in this case ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184858/discussion-between-ngoc-pham-and-niladry-kar).

Comment: Yeah It worked after rebooting my server...Thanx a lot@Ngoc Pham